# AirBnB React-dates not showing selected range

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, react-dates, react-day-picker

I'm trying to add [AirBnB React-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates). All of functionality working except one thing (Not opening the month of already  selected dates).

When I'm assigning the start and end dates then it selects the range but not showing the selected month. It showing the current month instead.

For example: If I set start date = 2017-05-05 and end date =2017-05-09 then it shows the selection, but in next time calendar picker open it only shows current month, so I have to click the next month, next month to see the previous selected dates;

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import moment from 'moment';

import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';


var SelectedStartDate = moment('2017-05-05');
var SelectedEndDate = moment('2017-05-09');


class HomePageDatePicker extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        focusedInput: null,
        startDate: SelectedStartDate,
        endDate:SelectedEndDate
    };
    this.onDatesChange = this.onDatesChange.bind(this);
    this.onFocusChange = this.onFocusChange.bind(this);
}

onDatesChange({ startDate, endDate }) {

    this.setState({ startDate, endDate });
}

onFocusChange(focusedInput) {
    this.setState({ focusedInput });
}

render() {
    const { focusedInput, startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <DateRangePicker
                {...this.props}
                onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
                onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
                focusedInput={focusedInput}
                startDate={startDate}
                endDate={endDate}                                     
                startDateId="datepicker_start_home"
                endDateId="datepicker_end_home"                    
                startDatePlaceholderText="Check In"
                endDatePlaceholderText="Check Out"
            />
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

When I open the picker, it shows February instead of May.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a selected state still like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import moment from 'moment';

import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';


var SelectedStartDate = moment('2017-05-05');
var SelectedEndDate = moment('2017-05-09');


class HomePageDatePicker extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        focusedInput: null,
        startDate: SelectedStartDate,
        endDate:SelectedEndDate
    };
    this.onDatesChange = this.onDatesChange.bind(this);
    this.onFocusChange = this.onFocusChange.bind(this);
}

onDatesChange({ startDate, endDate }) {

    this.setState({ startDate, endDate });
}

onFocusChange(focusedInput) {
    this.setState({ focusedInput });
}

render() {
    const { focusedInput, startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <DateRangePicker
                {...this.props}
                onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
                onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
                focusedInput={focusedInput}
                //Here is the change:
                date={startDate}
                startDate={startDate}
                endDate={endDate}                                     
                startDateId="datepicker_start_home"
                endDateId="datepicker_end_home"                    
                startDatePlaceholderText="Check In"
                endDatePlaceholderText="Check Out"
            />
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still its showing February month instead of showing May month. :'(

Comment: Yeah I just realized that you are using react-dates hrmm.  Woops!  Give me one second I'll try and code-pen something

Comment: I fixed it.  Try date={startDate}

Comment: @Mogan G, Still it is not working.  could u please give me the code-pen link? I'm using airbnb react date-range-picker.

Comment: Ok so I went to their github and downloaded their storybook and am running it locally, and  have  no issues with your code at all, have you tried to do that?  Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: @janie Try to not pass in {...this.props} as per https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/254 and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: date picker opened, but the months is not focused on the started date's month and console contains no error

Comment: Sorry at first I thought you were using date-picker.  But I am really not sure.  Do you want me to delete my answer, or leave it just in case someone else asks you to do exactly what I just made you do?  Sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136816/discussion-between-janie-and-morgan-g).

Answer (score 0):

Try this prop of DateRangePicker

```
initialVisibleMonth={() => startDate}
```